# The difference between 'in', 'to' and 'into'

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I cannot decide what is a proper preposition in a sentence below:

> Then place the discharged battery ***to*** the charger.

So is the preposition ***"to"*** right? I am not sure whether ***"in"*** or even ***"into"*** is the proper variant (because we put the battery not only *to* the charger, but actually *in* it for charging process to happen).

UPD: Can the word collocation **"place into"** be replaced with the word collocation **"put in"**?

Comment: You could use "connect" instead of the word "place". Then connect the discharged battery to the charger

Comment: It is different. That charger has actual slots for the batteries to be put in for charging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In technical language, batteries are placed in a charger. There are millions of hits on google for this. That is the technically correct way to say it.

If talking informally, you can say: "Just put the batteries in the charger, John."

Answer to your question: put x in the charger,informal. place x in the charger [technical, formal]

[place the battery in the charger: google hits for technical language](https://www.google.com/search?ei=Egu2W7PFFMLI_QaQsLOoBw&q=battery%20charger%20%2B%20%22place%20the%20batteries%20in%20the%22&oq=battery%20charger%20%2B%20%22place%20the%20batteries%20in%20the%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3..33i299l3.12537.15495..15845...1.0..1.118.470.3j2......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71.f5-TPm2zE8Y)

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to the context of direction/place:

`in` is used to express where something is in relation to a larger area:
`I am in the kitchen.`

`to` is used to express the movement towards a destination: `I am going to school.`

`into` is used to express that something/somebody is going inside somewhere. `She is going into the kitchen.`

In your case, the proper preposition to use would be `into`.

`Then place the discharged battery into the charger.`

Comment: Thank you so much! Could you also assist me, is it okay to replace word collocation **place ... into** with the word collocation **put ... in**?